# Avoid triggering 'child_added' for values I 'push' myself. Is it possible?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering if it's possible to avoid triggering a *child_added* event when I `ref.push()` a value myself, while still listening for new values added by others. I couldn't find anything relevant in the docs.

I know I can detect and ignore these cases if I need to but I was actually thinking of ways to reduce bandwidth usage, given that I can already find out if/when the value was inserted correctly with push() via its *onComplete* callback.

A solution I would like to avoid would be reading from one place and writing to another (as in different locations inside the same database). This could work for very simple applications but would otherwise get real messy real fast.

Just FYI, I don't have any specific use-case in mind. This is more of a theoretical "what if" scenario, stuff that comes to mind as I learn about Firebase.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The tried and test approach for this is to keep a local list of so-called *pending writes*. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32087031/how-to-prevent-value-event-on-the-client-that-issued-set/32098738#32098738

Comment: Thanks Frank but, as I said, I already know I can do that. This doesn't solve the bandwidth issue at all.